# How do I find the normal vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, 3d, surfaces, orthonormal

[image]

I think to find a tangent plane I have to find a normal vector to the plane, and know a point on the plane. I know a point is $(-2,3\pi/4, \pi/4)$ but I don't know how to find a normal vector.

Also, I am a bit confused - isn't $f(x,y,z)$ function of 3 variables which means the graph is 4D? So is it tangent "hyperplane"? Or is it regular 2D tangent plane?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you might want to go back to your sources and learn what a "level surface" is.

Comment: Hint: The gradient is parallel to the unit normal vector.

Comment: @JohnHughes Is the level surface this? $$x^2\sin(2y)\cos^2(z) = -2$$ then the graph would be in 3D and the tangent plane is regular 2D plane .... and I think to make it into a regular 2variable function I have to solve for $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ ... but then it is total mess, arccos and +/- everywhere

Comment: I found this from google search, is it good to use it? I think it is the same problem https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-b-chain-rule-gradient-and-directional-derivatives/session-37-example/MIT18_02SC_we_17_comb.pdf

Comment: @JohnHughes I think I solved it on answer. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @K.defaoite I think I solved it on answer. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: thanks both for help

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-b-chain-rule-gradient-and-directional-derivatives/session-37-example/MIT18_02SC_we_17_comb.pdf

The "level surface" is $$x^2 \sin(2y) \cos^2 (z) = -2$$

Then put a new variable $w$ so that $$w = x^2 \sin(2y) \cos^2(z)$$

Now have to find gradient on $w$:

$$\nabla w = \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x},\frac{\partial w}{\partial y},\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right) = \left(2x\sin(2y)\cos^2(z), 2x^2\cos(2y)\cos^2(z), -2x^2\sin(2y)\sin(z)\cos(z)\right)$$

Now to plug in point $P (-2, 3\pi/4, \pi/4) = (x,y,z)$ to this: $$\nabla w | P = \left(-4\sin(3\pi/2)\cos^2(\pi/4), 8\cos(3\pi/2)\cos^2(\pi/4), -8\sin(3\pi/2)\sin(\pi/4)\cos(\pi/4)\right)$$

so it is $$\nabla w | P  = \left(2,0,4\right)$$

this means tangent plane is: $$2(x+2)+4(z-\pi/4) = 0$$

which is same as $$2x + 4z = \pi -4 $$

Comment: Yep, looks correct to me.