# Let $f$ be defined on $ℝ^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. Is it possible to define $f(0, 0)$ such that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I've been self-learning mathematics and came across this question in a book. Can someone explain if this is possible and if so why?

> Let $$f(x, y) := \frac{1 − \cos(x^2 + y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$ be defined on $ℝ^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. Is it possible to define $f(0, 0)$ such that the function defined on all of $ℝ^2$ is continuous?

Comment: could you accept the answer if it was useful, Thanks in advance

Comment: Done! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x^2+y^2 = \alpha$ then
$$
f(x, y) := \frac{1 − \cos(x^2 + y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = \frac{1 − \cos(\alpha)}{\alpha^2}
$$
The limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ exists. You can check that by Taylor formula of the cosine.

Comment: limit is $0$? or $1/2$?

Comment: L'hopital rule says the limit is 1/2

Comment: yes, you're right

Comment: also can someone please look at my work on my question about tangent plane* to surface? not sure if I am right .. it is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3869860/181915 ... thank you